# Search Action Doesn't Work

Tags: symfony, search, entity

I have to do a search action in an entity that has a field that is located in another entity.

This is the field in the entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tipologia", inversedBy="recipes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tipologia_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $tipologia;

    /**
     * Set tipologia
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tipologia $tipologia
     *
     * @return Recipe
     */

    public function setTipologia(\AppBundle\Entity\Tipologia $tipologia = null)
    {
        $this->tipologia = $tipologia;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tipologia
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Tipologia
     */
    public function getTipologia()
    {
        return $this->tipologia;
    }
```

The field which I'm talking about is "tipologia".

I want to do the search action by this field, but if I call it "tipologia" I get an error.

This is the action:

```
public function searchrecipeAction(Request $request)
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $data = $request->request->get('search');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
                    'SELECT r FROM AppBundle:Recipe r
WHERE r.tipologia LIKE :data')
            ->setParameter('data', $data);

    $result = $query->getResult();

    return $this->render('default/searchrecipe.html.twig', [
        'result' => $result
    ]);
}
```

What can I do to make it work?
Thank you for every answer

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, you're comparing a string 'data' with an Entity tipologia. I'm assuming Tipologia contains fields (like name etc). To search for Recipes with a linked Tipologia with a name field like 'data', I'd suggest using the following query builder:

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Recipe');
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder('r')    
    ->leftJoin('r.tipologia', 't')
    ->where('t.name LIKE :data')
    ->setParameter('data', '%'.$data.'%');
```

Hope that helps; can't really help more without seeing which other fields the linked entity has.

Comment: Can you show me your Tipologia entity? I can help you through this if I know what fields you're trying to search within that entity.

Comment: Have you checked that your relationship is working? That query builder should definitely find any recipes with linked typologies with names matching your term.

Looking at your Tipologia class, I would suggest your relationship is wrong; should be:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Recipe", mappedBy="tipologia")
     */
    protected $recipes;
```

You should change your adder/getter/setter as well, obviously. If you have a Github repo for this, I'll happily have a look for you.

Comment: But when I add a recipe, I also che add the tipologia field, and I can save it in the DB and fetch it. So it's working, right? Or is not sure?

Comment: @KandeeHolly Can you put this on a Git repo and I'll have a look for you if that's easier?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Tipologia
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Tipologia
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Recipe", mappedBy="tipologia")
     */
    protected $tipologia;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tipologia = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Tipologia
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }



    /**
     * Add tipologium
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Recipe $tipologium
     *
     * @return Tipologia
     */
    public function addTipologium(\AppBundle\Entity\Recipe $tipologium)
    {
        $this->tipologia[] = $tipologium;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove tipologium
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Recipe $tipologium
     */
    public function removeTipologium(\AppBundle\Entity\Recipe $tipologium)
    {
        $this->tipologia->removeElement($tipologium);
    }

    /**
     * Get tipologia
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTipologia()
    {
        return $this->tipologia;
    }
}
```